# how i can perform search alphabetical with custom adapter in android

Tags: java, android

how i can perform search alphabetical with custom adapter  in android 
i tired so much and i cant fix my problem 
how i can filter my list view with alphabetical order

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer {

    private static  List<String> listItems;
    private Context context;
    private static String sections = "abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz";


    public SimpleAdapter(List<String> itemList,@NonNull Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.insurance_list, R.id.txtitem,listItems);
        listItems = itemList;
        this.context = ctx;
    }
```

Comment: Can you improve the question? I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to search or to filter? Filtering in alphabetical order doesn't make sense.

Comment: i want to make search alphabetically

Answer (score 2):

Sort your `listView` before set`ArrayAdapter` to it:

```
Collections.sort(listView, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to make search alphabetically